# UI Multipage with buttons on top

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, multipage

I'm trying to get my VBA user interface to look a little bit more professional, this is what I've got at the moment:

[image]

*That is a multipage object with two buttons - for adding and removing 'pages'.*

What I'd like it to look like is this: 
[image]

The issue is that I can't get the buttons to go on top of the multipage - they go to 'behind' no matter what I try. Is there any way to customise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug and you can do the following workaround:

- Insert a `Frame` control
- Put the Buttons <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> into that frame.

[image]

- Remove the caption of the frame
- Set its `BorderStyle` to `0 - fmBorderStyleNone`
  *(Note that because of another bug it initally was* `0 - fmBorderStyleNone` *and I had to switch forward to* `1 - fmBorderStyleSingle` *and back to 'none' remove the border.)*
- Place the frame and the buttons at the position you like.

[image]